# C# Layering transparent images

Tags: c#, image, transparency, visibility

I'm fairly new to working with c#, so I am sure there is a way to accompish this, but I have been unable to find an answer that works.

I am making a simple game where you create a pizza (similar to dominoes interactive ordering system). The user selects the toppings from a list and they appear on the pizza image. I planned to simply change the visibility of the topping .pngs when the items are selected, however, the last .png to appear covers up all previous ones.

I have tried using picture boxes and panels.

When using picture boxes, only the top visible image shows. I have the .pngs backgrounds set to transparent, and while they do show the form's background color, they mask the other .pngs.

When I used the panels, I had problems with the upper images parenting with the lower ones, so if I changed the visibility of the bottom one, all ones above it were hid as well.

I appreciate any help and advice.

Comment: Are you using WinForms (defaults to big gray rectangle), WPF (uses XML), or some other display framework?

Comment: WinForms, but I can change if that is the problem.

Comment: You need to nest the pictureboxes __in code__ and/or __subclass__ the panels for a working transparent background. Then it should work fine. But don't simply hide a panel or pb from the stack, or else all its children will disappear!! Instead either remove (set to null) the image or pull the image from the stack and put its child in its place..

Comment: Thanks! if I nest the picture boxes will it prevent me from showing the third and the fifth layers but not the rest?

Comment: Oh okay, just saw your update. That makes sense, I was so stuck on changing the visibility I didn't think of simply setting the image to null. Thanks!

Comment: yes. removing the panel/pb from the stack is more work but will allow you to draw on them; setting the image to null is simple as is replacing it with a fully transparent one. Do make sure you don't leak the bitmaps! And what Ashkan sugeests is a third way to do it..

Answer (score 0):

Mix images at runtime and add it to your picturebox:

```
       Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile("pizza.png"); //or get it from any other source
        Bitmap bmp2 = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile("over.png"); //or get it from any other source
        Bitmap bmpdest = new Bitmap(bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmpdest);
        g.DrawImage(bmp, new Point(0, 0));
        g.DrawImage(bmp2, new Point(0, 0));
        PictureBox1.Image = (Image)bmpdest;
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this if the other way gives me issues.

Comment: @MaryMoo the code had errors, I edited it please check it.

Comment: Use `New Bitmap(path)` instead of `FromFile`, then you got the right type without cast.